# umur = thnsaiki - thnlahir TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python-3.x

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

print ("######## $$ ########")
print ("#                  #")
print ("#     WELCOME.     #")
print ("#                  #")
print ("####################")
print ("")

#input your name
print ("Halo ...! ^_^")
name = input("Silahkan masukkan nama Anda : ")
print ("")
print ("Halo, "+name) 
print ("")

#showing today date
saiki = datetime.now()
tglsaiki = saiki.day
blnsaiki = saiki.month
thnsaiki = saiki.year
print ("Sekarang tanggal : ")
print ("{}/{}/{}".format(tglsaiki, blnsaiki, thnsaiki))

#input Date of Birth from user
print ("")
print ("Kami memerlukan informasi tanggal lahirmu!")
tgllahir = input("Masukkan tanggal lahir : ")
blnlahir = input("Masukkan bulan lahir (format angka) : ")
thnlahir = input("Masukkan tahun lahir : ")
print ("")
print ("Tanggal lahir ") , name , ":"
print ("{}/{}/{}".format(tgllahir, blnlahir, thnlahir))
print ("")

#Can or not make a driver's license SIM by age/umur
umur = thnsaiki - thnlahir
if umur >=17: #menggunakan pengurangan tahunnya aku
    print ("Selamat, Anda dapat membuat SIM")
elif umur <=17:
    print ("Mohon maaf, Anda belum dapat membuat SIM")

#delay setelah selesai, biar gk auto close
time.sleep(5) #delay 5seconds
```

Im created program that receives input in the form of date of birth with format dd / mm / yyyy. If the age of 17 years or more then the output is a message of 'You can create a SIM'. But if the age is less than 17 years old then the outgoing message 'Sorry, you are not old enough to create a driver'.
can anyone help? im new in python thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use `datetime` variables to compute distance between two dates via `timedelta`. Your `saiki` is OK and then you should convert `tgllahir`, `blnlahir` and `thnlahir` to another `date` (or `datetime`) in a variable named `lahir`.

Then you just perform the same logic

```
umur = saiki - lahir
```

and check if the year component is `<= 17`

For more details, please look at [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)

Comment: ok letme try it
btw thanks